# android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED does not launch activity at boot

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, manifest, intentfilter

I have a `BootUpReceiver` class which I'm attempting to use with `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` to launch an Activity when the device boots. The problem is - it does not seem to do so when I launch the app then restart the device.

I have verified there is no issue running Activity1.java - the issue lies either in the Manifest or the `BootUpReceiver` class but I'm not sure exactly why it will not launch after rebooting.

### BootUpReceiver.java:

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     Intent i = new Intent(context, Activity1.class); 
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i); 

 }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.com.idg.voiscphone"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.idg.voiscphone.Activity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

           <activity
            android:name="com.idg.voiscphone.Activity2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.idg.voiscphone.Activity3"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
              <activity
            android:name="com.idg.voiscphone.Activity3a"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
              <activity
            android:name="com.idg.voiscphone.Activity3b"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
       <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### Example Source:

http://androidrocksonmobility.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-auto-start-android.html

Comment: is your onreceive method calling??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"` and try again.

Beyond that, there is no requirement that your activity appear in front of any other activity that might be started around the same time, such as the home screen.

Comment: This didn't work for me; `onReceive()` still isn't called within my BroadcastReceiver

Comment: update: removing `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` and keeping `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` worked for me!