# RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED does not work

Tags: android, android-manifest, bootcompleted

I am trying to write in file after android device boots. I have checked everything related to this topic here but none of them worked for me. My phone is Huawei Honor (H30-U10) and it's rooted. Android version 4.2.2. Here is my code:

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bog.ddrc.technicianmobile"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="bog.ddrc.technicianmobile.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="bog.ddrc.technicianmobile.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name="bog.ddrc.technicianmobile.StartTMServiceAtBootReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**StartTMServiceAtBootReceiver.java:**

```
public class StartTMServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String data = "text";
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(path, "test.txt");

        try {
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            os.write(data.getBytes());
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.permission.RECEIVE\_BOOT\_COMPLETED does not launch activity at boot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763380/android-permission-receive-boot-completed-does-not-launch-activity-at-boot)

Comment: I don't want to launch activity. I want to write in file.

Comment: You asked to make `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` work. Have you read the accepted answer?..

Comment: Yes, I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Works for me but fair enough. Define "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED does not work" then...

Comment: I found the problem. I was launching the application from eclipse. It worked after I installed signed .apk file. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

from your `<receiver>` block.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all of mentioned answers and tricks, I finally find why the code is not work in my phone. Some Android phones like "Huawei Honor 3C Android 4.2.2" have a Statup Manager menu in their settings and your app must be checked in the list. :)